My last name is different in my Canadian visa
I just got my Canadian student visa and it's missing the - in my last name. So for example my name is MIKE AL-GOLD. On my Canadian student visa, it says MIKE ALGOLD. Is it OK or will they not let me travel? My candian visa does have the same number as my passport

Is this a vignette visa that is in the passport with the correct name?

What did the VAC/embassy say when you asked them?

@traveller I haven't asked them yet and to be honest I'm scared they would turn me away

@markjohnson  Yes its in my passport that has the correct name  it has the" - "and the canadian vignette visa is without the "-". Do you know if they would let me travel ?

From images I have seen Canadian vignette visa also contain the passport number. If that number is correct, then there should be no problem. (You should add this information to your question. Press 'Edit' to do this)

Not asking is not the way to go. If you ask and they say no, then you can fix the issue before you travel. If you don't ask then you get turned away at the border which is expensive and might have consequences.

@muaadh Not asking won’t make the fear go away.  And you’re still left with even more fear that the airline won’t let you board and/or Canadian Immigration will deny you entry. Contact the visa issuer and resolve your problem one way or another

I’m voting to close this question because the OP can only get a definitive answer from the visa issuer.

It should be fine as long as the numbers in my candian vignette visa and passport match, however I should still contact the visa issuer to make sure.
